# how to bypass multiple then in of mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I Don't want to make checks as `if (!isPresent)`  then do this ....

Is their any way to bypass all the  **then** when my work is complete

```
var isPresent=false;
    myPromise
            .then((employee) => {
                    if (employee) {
                        // throw 'employee already exist';
                        isPresent = true;
                        return res.data(mapper.toFullModel(employee));

                    }
                return model;
            });
            .then(model => {
                if (!isPresent) {
                    return new db.employee(model).save();
                }
            })
            .then(employee => {
                if (!isPresent) {
                    employee.token = auth.getToken(employee);
                    return employee.save();
                }
            })
            .then(employee => {
                if (!isPresent) {
                    res.data(mapper.toFullModel(employee));
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.failure(err);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your promise chain so the second part of it gets nested:

```
myPromise.then(employee => {
  if (employee) {
    return res.data(mapper.toFullModel(employee));
  }
  return new db.employee(model).save().then(employee => {
    employee.token = auth.getToken(employee);
    return employee.save();
  }).then(employee => {
    return res.data(mapper.toFullModel(employee));
  });
}).catch(err => {
  res.failure(err);
});
```

Comment: its the last then thats why its directly move out of it .. is their any other way like `break` statement that helps to break all  the .then.then part and go out of it..

Comment: No, promises aren't "cancelable", so you can't break out of a promise chain (unless you want to use hacks like throwing a custom error and handling those inside the `catch` handler).